# Solve initial-value differentialsystem corresponding to matrix $A$ of degree $2$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have proved that the eigenvalues of the following matrix are $-4,-1,2$ and $3$ by calculation of $p_A(\lambda) = (x+1)(x-2)(x-3)(x+4)$.

[image]

How can I solve the differentialsystem $$x_1^{''}=2x_2^{'}+x_1+2x_2, \\ x_2^{''}=-x_1^{'}-x_4+16x_2$$

with initial values $$x_1(0)=0, x_2(0)=-4 \\ x_1^{'}(0)=4, x_2^{'}(0)=26 $$

Up until now I have only solved systems of the form $x^{'} = Ax$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce two new variables $y_1$ and $y_2$ such that

$y_1 = x_1^{'}, \; y_2 = x_2^{'}; \tag{1}$

then set up (i.e., define) a vector of variables $\mathbf r$, thusly:

$\mathbf r = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ y_1 \\ y_2 \end{pmatrix}. \tag{2}$

Noting that the equations

$x_1^{''}=2x_2^{'}+x_1+2x_2, \tag{3}$

$ x_2^{''}=-x_1^{'}-4x_1+16x_2, \tag{4}$

can now be written

$y_1^{'} =2y_2+x_1+2x_2, \tag{5}$

$ y_2^{'}=-y_1-4x_1+16x_2, \tag{6}$

we see that (1), (5) and (6) may be combined into a single matrix-vector linear ODE

$\mathbf r^{'} = A\mathbf r, \tag{7}$

where $A$ is the matrix

$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 0 & 2 \\ -4 & 16 & -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}. \tag{8}$

(7) is of the familiar form $z' = Bz$, no explicit second derivatives here!  We take as intitial data for (7) $\mathbf r(0)$ with entries

$x_1(0)=0, x_2(0)=-4, y_1(0)=4, y_2(0)=26; \tag{9}$

the solution is then

$\mathbf r(t) = e^{At}\mathbf r(0), \tag{10}$

where $e^{At}$ may be evaluated using typical diagonalization methods; since the eigenvalues of $A$, which we already have at our disposal, are distinct, such techniques are relatively easy to apply.  I leave the details to you, my friends.

The key idea is to introduce new variables which are themselves *first derivatives* of the original variables, so that the resulting equation is of first order.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: Thank you @RobertLewis. Is it right that the result is very "ugly". I get something like: {{1/(21 E^(4 t)) + 5/(12 E^t) + E^(2 t) - (13 E^(3 t))/28, -4/(21 E^(4 t)) + 5/(6 E^t) - 2 E^(2 t) + (19 E^(3 t))/14, -5/(12 E^t) + (2 E^(2 t))/3 - E^(3 t)/4, 1/(21 E^(4 t))

Comment: cont.
- E^(2 t)/3 + (2 E^(3 t))/7}, {-5/(42 E^(4 t)) + 1/(12 E^t) + E^(2 t)/2 - (13 E^(3 t))/28, 10/(21 E^(4 t)) + 1/(6 E^t) - E^(2 t) + (19 E^(3 t))/14, -1/(12 E^t) + E^(2 t)/3 - E^(3 t)/4, -5/(42 E^(4 t)) - E^(2 t)/6 + (2 E^(3 t))/7}, {-4/(21 E^(4 t)) - 5/(12 E^t) + 2 E^(2 t) - (39 E^(3 t))/28, 16/(21 E^(4 t)) - 5/(6 E^t) - 4 E^(2 t) + (57 E^(3 t))/14, 5/(12 E^t) + (4 E^(2 t))/3 - (3 E^(3 t))/4, -4/(21 E^(4 t)) - (2 E^(2 t))/3 + (6 E^(3 t))/7}, {10/(21 E^(4 t)) - 1/(12 E^t) + E^(2 t) - (39 E^(3 t))/28, -40/(21 E^(4 t)) - 1/(6 E^t) - 2 E^(2 t)

Comment: cont. + (57 E^(3 t))/14, 1/(12 E^t) + (2 E^(2 t))/3 - (3 E^(3 t))/4, 10/(21 E^(4 t)) - E^(2 t)/3 + (6 E^(3 t))/7}} which should be multiplied by $r(0)$.

Comment: @user111854:  Wow!  I think that is the most amazing comment I have ever seen!  It's hard to read, however.  Perhaps you could $\LaTeX$ify it and put it in as an edit to your question, or even as an answer.  What is need is obviously $e^{At} = Pe^{Dt}P^{-1}$ where $D = P^{-1}AP$ is the diagonal form of $A$ and $P$ is the diagonalizing matrix of eigenvectors of $A$.  It's hard for me to tell if that's what you've written here!  But +1 for each of these incredible comments!  Cheers!